# Eclipse launch config fails : What does ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile() evaluate to

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to load a file from an eclipse launch configuration ( Debug > Debug Configuration). However i dont think my file is in the correct place to be recognized by the eclipse run time . Here is the code .

```
1 . Step 1 : Fetch the name of the program from the launch configuration 

2 . Step 2 : Check if the file exits .
```

I abort every single time .So it seems that my file is not at the correct position . But i am sure it is .

**EDIT**

I used the following API `String path ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(new Path(program)).getRawLocation().toString();` to determine the location that is being searched . However quite surprisingly the following API fails to see that the member exists in the path

**FAILING API**

```
String text = fProgramText.getText();
        if (text.length() > 0) {
            IPath path = new Path(text);
            if (ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().findMember(path) == null) {
                setErrorMessage("Specified program does not exist");
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            setMessage("Specify a program");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(new Path(program))
```

the getRawLocation() method:

```
String path = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(new Path(program)).getRawLocation().toString();
```

This gets you the system file name (fully qualified) of your file... or at least where Eclipse thinks your file should be.

If the file is where Eclipse is looking but Eclipse does't see it, you may have to send the refreshLocal() method to synchronize the workspace with the file systemm.  This is usually the case when you edit workspace fiels outside of Eclipse.

Comment: Yes i can see the location now . However the pain is that my file exists in that locaiton but this API ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().findMember(path) ignores it even though its present there . Any ideas ?